# Binary feature indicating 3 or more repeated characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have `str` like `"Buy new XXX sex bla-bla-bla"` and I need to find if `str` have `XXX` or `ZZZ`, or any 3 or more repeated characters. Of course I can do some array and go down the wrong way, but maybe is here some `trick`? Thank you.

PS. Google doesn't help.

Comment: so `bla` is counted in repeated characters?

Comment: no, I count characters, not words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

if re.search(r'(.)\1\1', mystr):
   print "Has triple letters"
```

Comment: `'.'` matches any character except newline, including space and tabs. You might want a more specific class such as Unicode alphanumeric/underscore: `r'(?u)(\w)\1\1'`

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
In [14]: for x,y,z in zip(strs,strs[1:],strs[2:]):
   ....:     if x==y==z and x:
   ....:         print x+y+z
   ....:         
XXX
```

Comment: Or using iterators: `izip(*[iter(strs)]*3)`.